# Checking if someone has a role to prevent reactions

Tags: python, discord.py

Making a support ticket like thing.  To prevent spamming of the reaction to make loads of tickets, I give them the role "help".  If they have this role, the check will not work, and not allow the reaction to do anything.  I am getting no errors, but it is not working either - you can still spam.

Btw the role adding works fine

Edit: new code (deletes message and resends new one) - now the second message when reacted to doesnt do anything - long error

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    helprole = discord.Object("851168291770597376")
    if user != bot.user and helprole not in user.roles:
     return str(reaction) == '⛑'
  while True:
   reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
   channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("⛑{}s-support-ticket".format(user.name))
   await channel.send("**This is your support ticket**\nPlease state your problem below\nA mod will be with you shortly")
   modchannel = bot.get_channel(839265539741188157)
   await modchannel.send("**NEW SUPPORT TICKET**\n<@&774589745664753665>\n<#{}>".format(channel.id))
   supportrole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="{}'s Ticket".format(user.name))
   role = supportrole
   helprole = discord.Object("851168291770597376")
   await user.add_roles(role)
   await user.add_roles(helprole)
   await msg.delete()
   await supportticket(ctx)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command supportticket:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 325, in supportticket
    await user.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 308, in supportticket
    try:
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/message.py", line 1022, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the bot has an administrator? If not, put it, in case it has it, check that if the bot has a role, it is above the other, and also that the role is properly configured.

Comment: the role is at the bottom so it should be fine... It can add it fine